# Port forwarding through nested docker containers on Jenkins

Tags: ruby, docker, jenkins, portforwarding

My Jenkins pipeline uses the docker plugin that then runs a docker container from inside of that to set up a general test environment like this:

```
   node('docker') {
    sh """
        cat > .Dockerfile.build <<EOF
        FROM ruby:$rubyVersion
        RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales && localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8
        ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8 \\
            LANGUAGE=en_US:en \\
            LC_LANG=en_US.UTF-8 \\
            LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

        RUN \\                  
          curl -sSL -o /tmp/docker.tgz https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/x86_64/docker-${dockerVersion}.tgz && \\
          tar --strip-components 1 --directory /usr/local/bin/ --extract --file /tmp/docker.tgz

        RUN \\
          groupadd -g $gid  docker && \\
          useradd -d $env.HOME -u $uid build -r -m && \\
          usermod -a -G docker build
        EOF

    """.stripIndent().trim()
    }
```

Once the test environment container is up, I run another container that has my code and tests inside that previously made environment container. One of my tests includes making sure a firewall was set up through iptables that allow certain ports through. To test to see if my firewall is setup correctly, I simple run this from inside that container (now 3 docker containers deep):

```
  def listener_response(port, host = 'localhost')
    TCPSocket.open(host, port) do |socket|
      socket.read(2)
    end
  rescue SystemCallError
    nil
  end
```

This is called by simply passing in the random port I used and the Jenkins docker node IP. When I run my test container, I do something like:

```
docker run -d -e DOCKER_HOST_IP=10.x.x.x -e RANDOM_OPEN_PORT=52459 -p 52459:52459 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

However, I still get a nil response from my test rather than an OK. Is there a way to port forward from the Jenkins host to my test environment to my test container?

Comment: In the innermost environment, are you connecting to `localhost` or to `ENV['DOCKER_HOST_IP']`?  What's the actual error you're getting?  There aren't "nested containers" _per se_, all of these calls reach out to the host's Docker daemon, and the `-p` option publishes a port on the outermost host.

Comment: @DavidMaze I am connecting to `ENV['DOCKER_HOST_IP']`, the `host='localhost'` portion is just the default value if one isnt supplied. The error I am getting is the SystemCallError, which i have to just return `nil`. By using `-p`, can i talk directly from the jenkins host node to the test container (skipping the environment/middle container)?

Comment: It seems kind of backwards to have an app test its host's firewall settings. The app shouldn't care. I'm not saying to reengineer your solution, but it seems like a poor separation of concerns at first glance.

Comment: @anothermh The host is testing the app's firewall. By opening the TCP socket using the host's IP and the port, I establish a TCP connection to the host on that port. Then I try to read, if i cant read, then the app firewall has it blocked and the `SystemCallError` is thrown and caught.

Comment: Why would the app know or care about a firewall? Again, seems like a poor separation but perhaps the overall setup is just not clear to me. I understand I'm not answering your question here so I won't keep cluttering up the comments. Good luck! 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the test environment with the option `--network host` seemed to solve the problem for me.